# How to add value to input with ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

my table have a field Id which is identity, autoincrement and zerofill, starts with 000001. Thats ok, Im using ajax and c# web service, my query is this:

```
sql = "Select Id FROM table WHERE (Owner ='" + us + "')";
```

This is my WebMethod

```
public string IdRegis(string us)
{
    string resp = "";
    DataTable dt = conn.ConsultTable("id", us);(This is query at top)

    Opc2 op;
    List<Opc2> lista = new List<Opc2>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        op = new Opc2((string)dt.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString());
        lista.Add(op);
        op = null;
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    resp = js.Serialize(lista);
    return resp;
}
```

And this is mi class

```
public class Opc2
{
   public Opc2() { }

   public Opc2(string item)
   {
       Item = item;
   }

   public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

And ajax success function:

```
 success: function (data) {
        var options = '<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select an option...</option>';
        var datas = JSON.parse(data.d);

        for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
            var id = ("00000" + (parseInt(datas[i].Id)));
            var zerofillid = id.substring(id.length - 5);

            options += '<option value ="' + zerofillid + '">';
            options += zerofillid;
            options += '</option>';
        }
        $('#id').html(options);
    }
```

My select gets this values 00NaN.

Comment: In your `success:` - `optiones` looks like a typo.

Comment: That was a mistake from copy paste, sorry.

Comment: For you zerofillid, use parseInt(id, 0) or just use the original datas[i].Id.  No need to build the string out just to parse it back down again.

Comment: `datas[i].Id`? Id is not a member of your class, how are you expecting it to appear in the ajax response array?

Comment: Can you post the result of `console.log(data)`;

Comment: @Nikhil Girraj Thanks!!! That was the problem, all this for copy and paste code jajaja, problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change your javascript loop as given below.

```
for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) 
{
    // changed id to Item in this line
    var id = ("00000" + (parseInt(datas[i].Item)));

    var zerofillid = id.substring(id.length - 5);

    optiones += '<option value ="' + zerofillid + '">';
    options += zerofillid;
    options += '</option>';
}
```